# Simplest way to unnest a BQ table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, unnest

I can directly unnest an array from a literal in BQ as follows:

```
select * from unnest([1,2,3])
# [{"f0_": "1"},{"f0_": "2"},{"f0_": "3"}]
```

How can I do the same from a `with` statement? For example, something like:

```
with Table as (
  select [1,2,3] as arr
 ) select * from unnest(Table.arr) ?? -- currently get unrecognized table name
```

What would be the correct syntax for the above? Here would be one example I came up with: is this the simplest way to do a general unnest?

```
with Movie as (
  select "Spider-Man" as Title, ['Sci-Fi', 'Action'] as Genres
 ) select Movie.Title, Genre from Movie cross join unnest(Movie.Genres) Genre
```

If so, why can't the above be done without a cross join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I do the same from a with statement?

```
with Table as (
  select [1,2,3] as arr
) 
select x from Table, unnest(arr) x
```

> is this the simplest way to do a general unnest?

Yes!

Comment: Thanks -- `table1, table2` is short for `table1 cross join table2` ?

Comment: that's right! comma in this case is the shortcut for cross join